# SQL parent table Childtable in one to many relationship

Tags: sql

I have the following two schemas for two tables

```
create table My_contacts
(
     Contact_ID, last name, first name, email, phone, profession_ID
)

Create table Profession
(
     Profession_ID, Profession Name
)
```

The relationship between tables `profession` and `My_contact` and is one-to-many.

I need a fast way to decide which one is parent table and which one is child table, so  my assumption is that because in the table My-Contacts has the foreign key profession_ID, it is the child table. (Based on primary key belongs to parent table, foreign key is in child table.)

However, I read the book Headfirst SQL, page P311. it says

> we moved the profession column into a new child table, and change the profession column in the parent table into foreign key profession_ID"
>   according to the above, the book means the profession table is the child table, and the my_contact table is the parent table.

I have tried to figure out this conflict, but could not.

Comment: thanks so much for editing this for me!

Comment: I was wandering if some one can give me some hints? Do I have wrong understanding on the child table and parent table concepts? Tks

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020343/what-are-parent-child-relationships) post.

Comment: According to this post
Relational databases such as SQL actually have no concept of parent/child relationships - that is an interpretation that you as a programmer put on the data. There are architectures that explicitly state and use such relationships, such as heirarchical (and to a certain extent OO) databases." I guess that's what I am looking for. Tks Mr. Giorgos Betsos!

Comment: The table _referencing_ another one is typically called the child table. The _referenced_ table is typically called the parent table. One reason for that is that a row in the parent needs to exist before you can insert a child (you can't have a child without a parent)

Comment: Tks so much a_horse_with_no_name, It makes sense!